# Universal Links query string removed/lost while generating share link, IOS, ReactNative Share

Tags: ios, react-native, hyperlink, sharing, universal

**Project workspace**

- Mobile Project: ReactNative 0.64.3 / Expo with Managed Workflow  / IOS 14.6 / NPM
- Sharing Library: ReactNative's default Share library.
- Website/Domain: Statically hosted via S3, single page app built with TS/Gatsby. Caching handled with CloudFront.

**Synopsis:** I'm using universal links and query params to allow my users to share tickets. The Universal links are being stripped of all route params and query strings when the link is shared by the native sharing dialog. Using the COPY/PASTE function in the native sharing dialog always copies a complete link, which can be pasted anywhere and used successfully to open the app. The EMAIL option also works, opening Mail with the correct url string and autofilled as expected. The problem arrises when I try to share the link via iMessage. I'm running the project on an iPhone as a fully deployed Apple Testflight standalone app.

- The app does download the AASA file on app install, which is statically hosted via an S3 bucket. I have verified its availability via postman and the online AASA validator here https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/
- The app always opens when opening a valid universal link, such as when I manually type it into iMessage or other sharing medium -- email, etc. Because of this, I'm inclined to believe I have a problem with where the link string is being generated rather than the AASA system.

```js
const ticketShare = (ticket: Ticket) => {
        const link = Linking.createURL("www.sample.com/share_ticket", { //Expo Linking library
            scheme: "https",
            queryParams: {
                ...ticket
            }
        }).replaceAll("%25", "%"); //double encoding problem I have yet to properly fix.
        console.log("link: ", link); //always the correct url here.

        Share.share({ url: link }); // request to open the native sharing dialog activity. ('url' for ios) 
    };
```

- Correct url is something like:
  https://www.sample.com/share_ticket?my=query&params=here
- Stripped url is something like:
  https://www.sample.com/

**sharing dialog image**.
https://www.sketchappsources.com/resources/source-image/simple-share-actionsheet-ios-13-hugo.png

- "COPY" actions always copy the correct url, "MAIL" works as well.
- Using "MESSAGE" or any of the "recent" actions in the top row fails, sharing the base url only.
  The title and website abbreviation at the top of the action sheet do render properly, pulling metadata/images from the website.

**To make it more complicated**, the share function **does** yield the correct url directly after a fresh install, but then never again. Console.logs always log the correct url.

I have tried react-native-share's library with the same results. (Wraps the same native bridge code?)

I have checked the react-native github page for issues related to this with no result. I have combed StackOverflow for a few days without results. Usually that means its something simple.. here's to hoping.
Anyone out there run into this issue? Thanks!

Comment: How about putting in the query parameter manually?

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to this? I have the same issue :(

Comment: Never figured it out!